# I'm trying to deploy a phoenix app to heroku but get an NPM error

Tags: node.js, heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework

I've been following the official docs to push the an phoenix 1.2.0 app using Elixir version 1.3.0 to Heroku but get the following error.

```
remote: Generated pages app
remote: -----> Creating .profile.d with env vars
remote: -----> Writing export for multi-buildpack support
remote: -----> Phoenix app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Loading configuration and environment
remote:        Loading config...
remote:        WARNING: phoenix_static_buildpack.config wasn't found in the app
remote:        Using default config from Phoenix static buildpack
remote:        Will use the following versions:
remote:        * Node 5.3.0
remote:        Will export the following config vars:
remote:        * Config vars DATABASE_URL
remote:        * MIX_ENV=prod
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        Downloading node 5.3.0...
remote:        Installing Node 5.3.0...
remote:        Using default npm version
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing and caching node modules
remote:        npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_f2aec913d61d8c51889992d9346679be/package.json'
remote:        npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON build_f2aec913d61d8c51889992d9346679be No description
remote:        npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON build_f2aec913d61d8c51889992d9346679be No repository field.
remote:        npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON build_f2aec913d61d8c51889992d9346679be No README data
remote:        npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON build_f2aec913d61d8c51889992d9346679be No license field.
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-93-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_f2aec913d61d8c51889992d9346679be/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_f2aec913d61d8c51889992d9346679be/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "--unsafe-perm" "prune"
remote:        npm ERR! node v5.3.0
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_f2aec913d61d8c51889992d9346679be/package.json
remote:        npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR! errno -2
remote:        npm ERR! syscall open
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_f2aec913d61d8c51889992d9346679be/package.json'
remote:        npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
remote:        npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote:        npm ERR! enoent 
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_f2aec913d61d8c51889992d9346679be/npm-debug.log
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Phoenix app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

This is the content of the elixir_buildpack.config

```
elixir_version=1.3.0
```

Any hint on what may be the cause of the error?

Comment: Is your node 5.3+ and npm 3+.Can you try to update your node version?

Comment: I've added an phoenix_static_buildpack.config file to set node and npm versions to 6.0.0 and 3.8.6 so that they could match the versions I use in dev.  But I get the same error/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project lacked a package.json and brunch-config.js. Adding those files solved the problem.

Comment: Anyone know if it's possible to skip all the frontend stuff? I don't server any HTML?

Comment: How is this done with an Umbrella App since the brunch-config.js and the package.js are in the lower directories in `/apps`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a phoenix_static_buildpack.config file in your app's root dir if you want to override the defaults. The file's syntax is bash.

If you don't specify a config option, then the default option from the buildpack's phoenix_static_buildpack.config file will be used.

Here's a full config file with all available options:

```
# Clean out cache contents from previous deploys
clean_cache=false

# We can change the filename for the compile script with this option
compile="compile"

# Add the config vars you want to be exported here
config_vars_to_export=(DATABASE_URL)

# We can set the version of Node to use for the app here
node_version=5.3.0

# We can set the version of NPM to use for the app here
npm_version=2.10.1

# We can set the path to phoenix app. E.g. apps/phoenix_app when in umbrella.
phoenix_relative_path=.
```

Here is complete [instructions](https://github.com/gjaldon/heroku-buildpack-phoenix-static)

Comment: I already had one to set the node and npm versions. Unfortunately, setting the other options didn't change anything.